# How to include file multiple times in PHP?

Tags: php

I have a standardized sequence of code which I used to display topic information on the home page and other pages on my site. I want to throw it in an include file so that I don't have to keep fixing multiple pages. The problem is sometimes this include occurs in a while statement which means there was a previous query supplying information for sorting purposes.

When the code is raw in the while statement, it works as it should and if there are multiple ids being served to the code from the previous query, it shows multiple results. However, if this code is in an include, I will only see one result. I assume because the include file only executes once. How would I serve an include file as the equivalent as my raw code?

**Include**

```
//outside query
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    $topic_id=htmlspecialchars( $row['topic_id'], ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8' );
    //code to display topics
    include('display_topics.php');  
}
```

**Raw Code**

```
//outside query
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    //code to display topics
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM topic WHERE id=?";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindValue(1,topic_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $result=$stmt->execute();
}

while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    //yada yada
    ...
}
```

Comment: Make it as a FUNCTION -- one of it's purposes is to implement a code snippet that can be called multiple times with (possibly) different arguments -- in other words "code reuse".

Comment: Would it be possible to restructure display_topics.php so it provides a function you call to perform its operations rather than having it just run?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP include file multiple times in one page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7403080/608639)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Don't do it this way.

It's much better to do *one* include, and to declare a [function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php) in it that does what you need:

```
function display_topics($topic_id)
 { 
   ....
 }
```

Call that function inside the loop, and pass all necessary data to it.

Comment: Ya, this is the better way to go :)

Comment: Curses! Foiled again by a concise answer!

Comment: Wow you are getting mad votes. That is the fastest I have seen +10.

Comment: @Scarface yeah, and I don't entirely understand why! It's not *that* outstanding an answer really. Ah well. :)

Comment: It's not the size, it's how you use it haha. It got the job done.

Comment: Pekka in order to be more efficient I wanted to execute the query and call the function after. This is also giving me one result. I am editing my question to show you what I am doing. Any suggestions on that? The include  with the function is at the top of the document.

Comment: @Scarface I guess you could put the entire second database query into the function too, and pass `$row` to it - not sure, it'll depend on what `show_videos()` does

Comment: The display_videos() function simply is a while statement getting the $row variables and then displaying information based on those variables. The problem is that when the query is in the display_videos function, it works but the queries sometimes vary so I was finding myself adding all these function parameters depending on where the display_videos was used so I thought maybe there was a better way like just executing the query and then calling the function but then I get the previous issue where I only get one result regardless.

Comment: I am just going to pass the query through like you said, and since I am using PDO I am going to pass the parameters in an array or something and then deal with them in the function. Thanks again Pekka.

Answer (score 1):

Include the file as normal, but put the repeated code in a function.  Then, where you wish to add the code simply call the function.

Answer (score 1):

That word, I don't think it is for what you think it is for.

Generally, `include`'s use should not be used that way. That's why God invented functions (or Ada Byron, if you're not theologically inclined).

Try this instead:

```
function execute_row($row, $conn)
{
    $topic_id=htmlspecialchars( $row['topic_id'], ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8' );
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM topic WHERE id=?";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindValue(1,topic_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    return $stmt->execute();
}
```

Then, in your while statement:

```
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    $result = execute_row($row, $conn);
}
```

TADA! And the best part is, it makes your code smaller, easier to read, and faster to parse.

Comment: I agree functions should be used, but within an include in this case. This function is reoccurring on about 7 different pages so the reason I even thought of include was so I did not have to go around fixing all these pages, I could just fix one.

Comment: @Scarface you would keep the function in one location location. Or if they're 7 similar but different ones, the next step would be to build a function so abstract that it can serve all 7 purposes.

Comment: Are you referring to OOP type techniques?