# PHP include file multiple times in one page

Tags: php, include

I have a php-file called `kal_test.php` which gives a value to the variable `$vbl`. This variable is needed in the file called `kal_generator.php` which produces a table from that variable (I'll spare you the details). It goes like this:

---

[kal_test.php]

```
<?php
$vbl = "14/09/2011";
include ("kal_generator.php");
?>
```

[kal_test.php]

```
<?php
// Long code converts the $vbl into a 2-dimensional array called $output
// I'll spare you the details (it works fine by the way)
?>

<table>
  <tr><th>bla</th><th>blabla</th></tr>

<?php
foreach ($output as $v1) {
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach ($v1 as $v2) {
        echo "<td>$v2</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
?>

</table>
```

---

This set-up works fine but I can't make two of those appear on the same page, like this:

[kal_test.php]

```
<?php
$vbl = "14/09/2011";
include ("kal_generator.php");
$vbl = "21/09/2011";
include ("kal_generator.php");
?>
```

This will give the following result:

```
//here comes the header

<table> // table created with $vbl = "14/09/2011"
  <tr><th>bla</th><th>blabla</th></tr>
  <tr><td>this</td><td>works</td></tr>
  <tr><td>this</td><td>works</td></tr>
</table>

//here should the second table be and also the rest of the page (footer), this is completely missing
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: Don't do this.  Put a function in that include and call the function every time you need it.

Comment: I'd love to do that but the long code is (surprise!) really long

Comment: Who cares.... What is so hard about wrapping it up with the `function` keyword and a couple brackets?  Perhaps you should consider breaking that function into a few functions while you're at it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're likely defining a function or class  in `kal_generator.php`. PHP aborts when you try to redefine such a function or class. Consider putting your code in a function, include that function once and then run the function instead of including a file.

#### kal_test.php

```
<?php
require_once 'kal_generator.php';
kal_generator("14/09/2011");
kal_generator("21/09/2011");
?>
```

#### kal_generator.php

```
<?php
function kal_generator($vbl) {
    /**
     * Here, you should be creating $output
     */
    echo <<EOF
<table>
  <tr><th>bla</th><th>blabla</th></tr>

EOF;
    foreach ($output as $v1) {
        echo "<tr>";
        foreach ($v1 as $v2) {
            echo "<td>$v2</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>\n";
    }

    echo "</table>\n";
}
?>
```

Comment: Brad said the same, I'll try this but it will take a long time to rewrite the code. I should have thought about this earlier :(

Comment: @gieldl, what rewriting is there to do?

Comment: If it's that long, you've done something wrong. Break the code down in parts (functions, methods, whatever).

Comment: With the code we've been given in the example, then Brad is correct; there's virtually zero rewriting. However, I have had to work with badly written code in the past which worked very much as per the question, and it was very hard to rewrite so I know it can be painful. But I would still say you should do it. If the code is bad enough that it is hard to rewrite per this answer, then that is a sure sign that it *needs* to be rewritten!

Comment: by the way -- one other thing: if you're going to use this answer, you might want to use the `include_once()` function rather than `include()`. (it won't make any difference, but might save you from errors later if you accidentally try to include it twice)

Comment: @Spudley: If there is a class or file defined, I always use `require_once` to avoid later crashes which occurs if an inexistent or function is used without checking for its existence. Good suggestion on using `*_once` though.