# Include same file multiple times in PHP

Tags: php, include

Basically I have a list of particular members that I am calling with their member ID, and displaying the td's afterwards on each one..

So I have the table like this

```
    <table id="sortable" class="tablesorter" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="header"><strong>Game Username</strong></th>
      <th class="header"><strong>Rank</strong></th>
      <th class="header"><strong>Game Played</strong></th>
      <th class="header"><strong>Playing On</strong></th>
      <th class="header"><strong>Age</strong></th>
      <th class="header"><strong>Time On</strong></th>
      <th class="header"><strong>Location</strong></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php include ("users.php"); ?>
  </tbody>
```

And the users.php file looks like this, but right now at over 50 lines of the same code as below, with only the $id= number changed..

```
<tr><td class="username"><a href="<?php $id='1'; include ("fields.php"); ?>
<tr><td class="username"><a href="<?php $id='2'; include ("fields.php"); ?>
<tr><td class="username"><a href="<?php $id='3'; include ("fields.php"); ?>
<tr><td class="username"><a href="<?php $id='4'; include ("fields.php"); ?>
<tr><td class="username"><a href="<?php $id='5'; include ("fields.php"); ?>
```

The fields.php file is the remainder of the table rows etc., starting with the below code to close off this td.

```
<?php echo $domain; $member_id = $id; $user_info = get_userdata($id);echo $user_info-> user_login.""; ?>"><?php echo xprofile_get_field_data( "$field_gamename" , $member_id); ?></a>
</td>
```

I'm trying to avoid including the fields.php file over 50 times in the users.php file. Anyone got an idea of the most efficient way?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP include file multiple times in one page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7403080/php-include-file-multiple-times-in-one-page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
<?php for ($i=0; $i<50; $i++): ?>
<tr><td class="username"><a href="<?php $id=$i; include ("fields.php"); ?>
<?php endfor; ?>
```

On the other hand, you should probably re-factor your code so that you do not need to include the file on each loop, probably by either putting the code inline or (much better) by creating a function that does whatever you need to be done, something like this:

```
<?php for ($i=0; $i<50; $i++): ?>
<tr><td class="username"><a href="<?php do_some_stuff($i); ?>
<?php endfor; ?>
```

EDIT:

Since you want this to work for a defined list of IDs, you should create an array with that list and loop through it using the foreach() statement, like this:

```
<?php 
$IdArray = array(1, 2, 25, 38);
foreach ($IdArray as $id): ?>
<tr><td class="username"><a href="<?php include ("fields.php"); ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Notice that I have removed the "$id = $i", since I am feeding the $id variable directly inside the foreach statement! ;)

BTW, you should close the tr, td and a tags before the "endforeach", ok?

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you Thomas! The first line of code, php for works well except it does all the users from 1-50. How can I define specific ids, since the ones I need to display are completely random. I will accept this answer shortly. Maybe something like <?php for ($i=1,3,24,85; $i++): ?>

Comment: Or could I wrap the for statement with an if statement, that will only display users if they have a specific field filled.<?php if ( $rank == 'Recruit' ); ?>
<?php for ($i=0; $i<50; $i++): ?>
<tr><td class="username"><a href="<?php $id=$i; include ("fields.php"); ?>
<?php endfor; ?>
<?php endif; ?>

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay! If you have an array with the list of IDs you want, you should use foreach instead! I will edit the answer to reflect the solution, ok?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a **[loop](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php)**.

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 50; $i++) {
    //Do stuff with $i.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
for($i = 0; $i <= 50; $i++) {
?>
<tr>
    <td class="username">
        <?php $href = $domain . $user_info->get_userdata($i) . $user_info->user_login;?>
        <a href="<?php echo $href;?>"><?php echo xprofile_get_field_data( "$field_gamename" , $i); ?></a>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php
}
?>
```