# File include only once in foreach loop why ?

Tags: php, foreach, include

I want to include file in foreach loop but it included only once time why..

There are 3 orders stores in my database and i want to include `info_customer.php` 3 times but it's only included only one time.

Following is my code..

```
<?php
$ordersinfo = $ordercon->get_orders_by_ids($p_order_id);

    foreach ($ordersinfo as $key => $customerInfo) {
        $customerDeliveryMethod = $customerInfo['delivery_method'];
        if($shipping_method == 5 && $customerDeliveryMethod == 'startrack'){
            $_POST['delivery_type'] =$customerDeliveryMethod;                       
        }elseif ($shipping_method==5 && $customerDeliveryMethod == 'austpost') {
            $_POST['delivery_type'] =$customerDeliveryMethod;
        }
        include("info_customer.php");
    }

?>
```

Why file include only once , i want to included

Comment: What do you have in your `$ordersinfo` ? If there's only one record, the file will be included only once

Comment: so you have methods to gather information about your order in info_customer.php and you need to include it 3 times? You can just include it once and call those methods as you need it.

Comment: @Zyigh There are 3 records in $ordersinfo so file must be include 3 times not only one time.

Comment: @WKoppel , Yes i include it 3 times.

Comment: I think this link may help you [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7403080/php-include-file-multiple-times-in-one-page).

Comment: Do you send data to infos_costumer.php ?

Comment: Too much information is missing to really answer your question. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve I also wonder why you assign a value to `$_POST`? Yes, you can do that, but it means that `$_POST` no longer contains what has been posted: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php

Comment: can you add `info_customer.php` to the question?